# Learn dynamics-crm programming at home

Tags: dynamics-crm

I want to learn dynamics-crm on my own and I have few questions.

1. Since it is not a free product, is there any way to run my code and test it (free)?
2. I am a PHP + Java + mysql/sqlserver programmer, I have seen c# syntax and I c that it is similar to Java, is that a good idea to study alone?
3. Where can I find good online resources to study from?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1) Microsoft offers a free 30 day trial for Dynamics CRM Online.  You could probably get a new one when the old expires. http://crm.dynamics.com/en-us/trial-overview

2) Extending Microsoft CRM entails knowledge of C# and JScript.  You should make the jump to C# if you want to be able to write plugins and such.

3) The best resource is definitely the Dynamics CRM 2011 SDK - It contains a lot of samples and is very well documented in its help file.  It can be downloaded at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24004.  The CRM Developer Training Kit can be found at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23416.  There are more good resources at the CRM Developer Center - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm/bb467596.

Comment: any way to get it installed? if not. developing for the cloud is the same as for installed? tx

Comment: CRM 2011 Online now has most of the same features as on-premise.  Main differences are that all your custom code will have to retrieve data via the web services vs. having direct SQL access for reads.  CRM Online is definitely good enough to learn the platform, how to create C# plugins, how to create form JScript.  There is also a CRM 2011 VPC available for Microsoft partners @ <http://blogs.msdn.com/b/midatlanticcrm/archive/2011/05/24/new-crm-2011-vpc-has-been-released-to-partners.aspx>.